# Div and ul list side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I am trying to place a ul list at the side of a div. The ul should begin at the right side and at the top of the div, and end on the bottom side of the div.

The problem is that it starts at the bottom of the div, not at the top of it. How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#map").prepend('<img src="images/d2.png">');

 var width = $("#map > img").attr("width");
 $("#actions").css("width", width);
});
```

```css
body {
 margin:     0;
 padding:    0;
}

nav {
 -webkit-transition:  width 0.3s;
 -moz-transition:  width 0.3s;
 -o-transition:   width 0.3s;
 transition:    width 0.3s;
 position:    fixed;
 height:     100%;
 width:     60px;
 background:    blue;
 z-index:    1;
}

nav:hover {
 width:     200px;
}

div#painel {
 padding-left:   60px;
 background:    red;
 width:     calc(100%-60px);
 display:    block;
 z-index:    0;
 text-align:    center;
}

div#map-container {
 padding:    20px 0 20px;
 width:     100%;
 background:    green;
 text-align:    center;
}

#map-interface,
div#map {
 display:    inline-block;
 border:     0;
 padding:    0;
 margin:     0;
}

#map-interface {
 background:    gray;
 list-style:    none;
 margin-left:   -4px;
 height:     488px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
  </nav>

  <div id="painel">
   <div id="map-container">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <ul id="map-interface">
     <li>asda</li>
     <li>asd</li>
     <li>asdsad</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Inside the div#map, I have an image, and inside the list I will have a menu to interact with the image. The ul list should be a block with the same size as the image (or the div).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `#map-interface { vertical-align:top; }` to align inlined-block content to their tops.